# How to select one column from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to select one same column from 3 tables and get a rows from this one column.

Here is the code:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * from tv,movies WHERE hash='123'");
```

So now i want the column called hash from the tv and movies to bring result from the hash number.

---

### I don't have the the same columns number in tv and movies.

Make sure if the hash doesn't exist in tv then go to movies.

Comment: What language are you using? Is it PHP? Probably you should tag this question with sql an php tags at least.

Comment: @Occulta yes `mysql_query` is PHP function, I've retagged the question properly.

Comment: i'm using php with mysql

Answer (score 1):

## Make it one table with `category` field in it.

that's the only proper way of designing a database.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT fieldName1 FROM table1 WHERE hash='123'
 UNION
SELECT fieldName1 FROM table2 WHERE hash='123'
 UNION
SELECT fieldName1 FROM table3 WHERE hash='123';
```

Comment: but i don't have the same number of columns in both tv and movies

Comment: @Ahmed Jalal: you said, "I want to select one same column" and this SQL code indeed selects one column, Why does it matter whether you have the same number of columns in both `tv` and `movies`?

Comment: it didn't work, i checked it.
when i fetch arrays it doesn't find the other columns

Comment: how do we select either from tv or movies, like if the hash exist in tv proceed and if not go to movies

Answer (score 0):

You have to select equal number of columns in both tables

```
SELECT tvcol1 as field1,tvcol2 as field2 from tv WHERE hash='123' 
UNION 
SELECT moviescol1 as field1,moviescol2 as field2  from movies WHERE hash='123'
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines and based on your comments to @Bryan's answer, you want all the columns from the `tv` table, but if it's not found select all the columns from the `movies` table. In that case use two different queries:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tv WHERE hash = '123'") or die( mysql_error() );

if( mysql_num_rows( $result ) == 0 ) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE hash = '123'") or die( mysql_error() );
}
```

Now `$result` has the columns from either `tv` or `movies` table, or `false` if the hash wasn't found in either of them.